# How To Make Selected Columns the Same Width in a PowerPoint Table?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Is there a way to programmatically make only some columns in a PowerPoint table the same width? It should be their combinded width, divided by the number of columns, but I can't figure out a way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I've answered this before somewhere, couldn't seem to find that reference. Here's the code you'll need, just make sure you have the columns selected that you want to be distributed evenly

```
Sub DistributeSelectedColumnsEvenly() 
Dim sel As Selection 
Set sel = ActiveWindow.Selection 
Dim fColumn As Integer 
fColumn = 0 
Dim lColumn As Integer 
Dim columnsWidth As Integer 

With sel 
    If .Type = ppSelectionShapes Then 
        If .ShapeRange.Type = msoTable Then 
            Dim tbl As Table 
            Set tbl = .ShapeRange.Table 
            Dim tblColumnCount As Integer 
            tblColumnCount = tbl.Columns.Count 
            For colNum = 1 To tblColumnCount 
                If tbl.Cell(1, colNum).Selected Then 
                columnsWidth = columnsWidth + tbl.Cell(1, colNum).Parent.Columns(colNum).Width 
                    If fColumn = 0 Then 
                        fColumn = colNum 
                    End If 
                    lColumn = colNum 
                End If 
            Next 
            Dim columnCount As Integer 
            columnCount = (lColumn - fColumn) + 1 
            Dim columnWidth As Integer 
            columnWidth = columnsWidth / columnCount 
            For columnIndex = fColumn To lColumn 
                tbl.Columns(columnIndex).Width = columnWidth 
            Next 
        End If 
    End If 
End With 
End Sub
```

Comment: Wowser, this is really great. I'll test it out now!